# How to connect JSON that is unmarshaled to an HTML page using golang?

Tags: html, arrays, json, go

I've reached the point where I have unmarshaled my JSON and I can print the data directly from the registry.go file. What I don't understand (and I'm new to golang and backend dev) is how to connect that data to my html page. I would very much appreciate if someone could explain to me how to do this.

I have seen some examples, but they are all in one file, I want to keep the JSON, HTML, and Go pages separate. The JSON is being pulled directly from an API, and there will be multiple HTML pages using that data.

Here is an example, very close to the JSON I'm using, it is being pulled from an API:

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "some text",
            "displayName": "some more text",
            "status": {
                "status": "UP",
                "lastUpdate": "2020-07-21T12:42:24.968647Z"
            },
            "type": "test"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "some text",
            "displayName": "some more text",
            "status": {
                "status": "UP",
                "lastUpdate": "2020-07-21T12:42:24.968647Z"
            },
            "type": "test"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "description": "some text",
            "displayName": "some more text",
            "status": {
                "status": "UP",
                "lastUpdate": "2020-07-21T12:42:24.968647Z"
            },
            "type": "test"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "description": "some text",
            "displayName": "some more text",
            "status": {
                "status": "UP",
                "lastUpdate": "2020-07-21T12:42:24.968647Z"
            },
            "type": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the registry.go page I am using. I have a separate main.go page as I have other pages that have been created. I am trying to keep this piece separate, but if I cannot please tell me.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

// Results struct which contains
// an array of results
type Results struct {
    Count   int      `json:"count"`
    Results []Result `json:"results"`
}

// Results struct which contains the ID and description
type Result struct {
    ID          int    `json:"id"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    DisplayName string `json:"displayName"`
    Status      Status `json:"status"`
    Type        string `json:"type"`
}

// Status struct
type Result struct {
    Status      string `json:"status"`
    LastUpdated string `json:"lastUpdated"`
}

func main() {
    // Open the jsonFile
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("test.json")
    // if os.Open returns an error then handle it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened test.json")
    // defer the closing of the jsonFile in order to parse it later on
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    // read the opened xmlFile as a byte array.
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    // initialize the results array
    var results Results

    // unmarshal the byteArray
    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &results)

    // Print the count
    fmt.Println(results.count)
    // iterate through the results and print
    for i := 0; i < len(users.Users); i++ {
        fmt.Println("ID: " + results.Results[i].ID)
        fmt.Println("Desctiption: " + results.Results[i].Description)
    }
}
```

And here is the html page I have created (test.html), just showing the body piece:

```
<body>
    {{range .}}
        <div>
            <h3>{{.DisplayName}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div>{{.Id}}</div>
        <div>{{.Description}}</div>
        <div>{{.Type}}</div>
    {{end}}
</body>
```

In Main.go I have the following references:

```
//handler to display the page
http.HandleFunc("/test", hndlerTest)

//hndlerTest - the Testing Page
func hndlerTest(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    renderTemplate(w,"test.html", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [html template package](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) to parse and render html filed and write the executed template to your http response. You can refer to the following example to start with.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var htmlFile = `
<body>
    {{range .Foos}}
        <span>Foo: {{.Foo}}</span>
    {{end}}
</body>
`

var jsonData = `[{"foo":1},{"foo":2},{"foo":3}]`

type foo struct {
    Foo int `json:"foo"`
}

type Data struct {
    Foos []foo
}

func main() {
    var d Data
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &d.Foos); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Use template.New("index").ParseFiles("index.html") for files
        templ, err := template.New("index").Parse(htmlFile)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        if err := templ.Execute(rw, d); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    })
    log.Panic(http.ListenAndServe(":3030", nil))
}
```